# How to do memory profiling on remote java web application

Tags: java, memory, profiling

I know we can use tools like JProfiler etc.
Is there any tutorial on how to configure it to display the memory usage just by remote monitoring?

Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

you have VisualGC, it's not very advanced but you can see the memory usage of your application (garbage,old, perm etc...)

[http://java.sun.com/performance/jvmstat/visualgc.html](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstatd.html)

to resume : 
you launch a daemon monitoring on the remote machine (http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstatd.html, see the security parapraph)

```
JAVA_HOME/bin/jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=jstatd.all.policy
```

with a file here called **jstatd.all.policy** containing :

```
    grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {   
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

on the remote machine you got the pid of your application to debug with the jps tool :

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html#jps

finally on your local machine you launch the visualgc :

```
visualgc the_pid@remote_machine_address
```

Answer (score 7):

I usually use YourKit which is an excellent application (license needed).

In your webservers startup/shutdown script (catalina.sh for tomcat) put in:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -agentlib:yjpagent -Xrunyjpagent:sessionname=Tomcat"
```

You'll need YourKit already downloaded and added to your library path (I do this in catalina.sh as well):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/yourkit/yjp-6.0.16/bin/linux-x86-32
```

You can then launch the YourKit client on your local desktop and remotely connect.

Answer (score 3):

You can change to VM params of your Java application to allow remote profiling
something like `-agentlib:jprofilerti=port=25000`

[General explanation of JProfiler](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/).

Examples:

- [NetBeans](http://profiler.netbeans.org/docs/help/5.5/attach.html#direct_attach)
- [Intellij](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=253)

Answer (score 1):

Profile your application using Jprofiler. Below are the steps to configure your Tomcat with Jprofiler.

1. In Linux machine open `.bash_profile` file from `/root` directory.
   Enter jprofiller location (using below command export) in

   ```
   .bash_profile file
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/dsvol/jprofiler6/bin/linux-x86
   ```
2. Go Tomcat installation directory. Open `catalena.sh` file from `bin` folder.
   Enter the below details in `catelana.sh` file (only red color information and black color you can find by default in catalena.sh file).

   ```
   export JPROFILER_HOME
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms768m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -agentpath:/opt/Performance/jprofiler7/bin/linux-x86/libjprofilerti.so=port=8849 $CATALINA_OPTS"
   ```
3. Start the server from bin folder by executing the `starup.sh` command

Answer (score 0):

I've heard good things of VisualVM and here is an article on how to it up remotely:

[Java VisualVM to profile a remote server](http://www.codefactorycr.com/java-visualvm-to-profile-a-remote-server.html)

**EDIT**:
I wrote a blog post on how to setup remote profiling through an SSH tunnel here:

http://kamilmroczek.com/2012/11/16/168787859/

Comment: This is link only. Please add more information on your answer

Comment: VisualVM does not support memory profiling on remote machines, only CPU profiling